# python abrir y leer todos archivos de carpeta y guardar en un solo archivo procesado

Tags: python

Buen día estimados, requiero de favor su apoyo, requiero crear un un programa en python que lea todos los archivos de una carpeta linea por linea y extraer partes de algunas lineas especificas,es decir,solo lo que este despues de logued user:,Nombre de host:,Modelo el sistema:y SERIAL NUMBER: que para ello utilicé una expresión regular. El programa ya me funciona haciéndolo especificando un solo archivo, pero requiero que abra un primer archivo y una vez procesado comience con los demás archivos de la carpeta.
Tendrán alguna idea?
NOta:todos los archivos de la carpeta tienen una estructura mas o menos asi:

logued user:fulano

linea que no interesa

Nombre de host:fulano

linea que no interesa

Modelo el sistema:fulano

SERIAL NUMBER:

se guardan en un archivo separado por comas, la intención es posteriormente abrirlo en excel.
También agradecería si tuvieran idea de como mejorar el código
Mil gracias anticipadas

```
import re
cabecera='Logued user,Nombre de host,Modelo el sistema,SERIAL NUMBER\n'
rutaguardar='C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/reporte.cvs'
archivo=open(rutaguardar,'w')
archivo.write(cabecera)
with open('//servidor/resultados/archivo1.txt','r') as rutaorigen:
    for linea in rutaorigen:
       if linea.startswith('Logued user'): 
           m = re.search('Logued user: (.+?)\n', linea)
           if m:
                extraido=m.group(1)
                archivo.write(extraido)
                archivo.write(',')
       if linea.startswith('Nombre de host'):
           m = re.search('Nombre de host:                            (.+?)\n', linea)
           if m:
                extraido=m.group(1)
           archivo.write(extraido)
           archivo.write(',')
       if linea.startswith('Modelo el sistema'): 
           m = re.search('Modelo el sistema:                         (.+?)\n', linea)
           if m:
                extraido=m.group(1)
           archivo.write(extraido)
           archivo.write(',')
       if linea.startswith('SERIAL NUMBER'):
           m = re.search('SERIAL NUMBER: (.+?)\n', linea)
           if m:
                extraido=m.group(1)
           archivo.write(extraido)
           archivo.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Estoy asumiendo que todos los campos que te interesan siempre tiene un valor, con eso en mente el código queda así, espero te haber ayudado:

```
import os

cabecera = "Logued user,Nombre de host,Modelo el sistema,SERIAL NUMBER\n"
cuerpo = ""

direccion = "//servidor/resultados"
archivos = os.listdir(direccion)
datos = [ ar for ar in archivos if ar.endswith( (".txt") ) ]

for txt in datos:
    archivo = open(direccion + "/" + txt, "r")
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        if linea.find("logued user")>= 0:
            linea = linea.split(":")
            linea = linea[1].replace("\n", "")
            cuerpo += linea + ","
            
        if linea.find("Nombre de host")>= 0:
            linea = linea.split(":")
            linea = linea[1].replace("\n", "")
            cuerpo += linea + ","
            
        if linea.find("Modelo el sistema")>= 0:
            linea = linea.split(":")
            linea = linea[1].replace("\n", "")
            cuerpo += linea + ","
            
        if linea.find("SERIAL NUMBER")>= 0:
            linea = linea.split(":")
            linea = linea[1].replace("\n", "")
            cuerpo += linea + "\n"
        
    archivo.close()

archivo = open("C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/reporte.cvs", "w+")
archivo.write(cabecera + cuerpo)
archivo.close
```